# Audio volume change is lagging

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im playing two tracks in sync. This works well, they sound like one song.
What im trying to do is allow player to switch one track on and of by toggling mute or setting volume to 0 or 1. The muted track continues playing in sync with other track but cant be heard.

But the volume change /muting is lagging. So even if you switch the sound on exactly on beat you wont hear that beat cause it takes a split second for the code to react. There must be a way to make the change instant?

Below is a part of the music manager that handles this. The full code also includes how sound is loaded and starts playing and can be seen here:
https://github.com/Lautaro/AudioTest/blob/master/Assets/MusicManager.cs

```
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Toggle();
        }
    }
}

void Toggle()
{
    var clip = Sources.First(s => s.clip.name == "ExtraBeat");
    // Same result if setting clip.volume instead of mute
    clip.mute = !clip.mute;
}
```

The complete project with audio tracks can be cloned here. Use space to toggle sound.
https://github.com/Lautaro/AudioTest.git

Comment: Please add a Minimal code example here to your question. I do not want to clone and parse an entire project until eventually finding the class and Codeblock where your issue appears.

Comment: @derHugo Sorry! Ive updated OP